# JUnit4 : testing for expected exception

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I'm trying to test with *JUnit4* a method throwing an exception. Here is the code snippet :

```
package unit_tests;

import org.junit.Test;
import calculator.*;

@Test(expected=CalcError.class)
public void testDivision() {
    Calculator myCalc = new Calculator(10, 0);
    myCalc.setOperation(Calculator.Operation_e.DIVIDE);
    myCalc.getResult();
}
```

The problem is with the line `@Test(expected=CalcError.class)`: I get the following error :

```
Class<CalcError> cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here is how `CalcError` is defined :

```
package calculator;

public class Calculator {
    public class CalcError extends Exception {
        // ...
    }

    public double getResult() throws CalcError {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `CalcError` is not a type, even though the unit tests are in a `unit_tests` package and the calculator is in a `calculator` package.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Could you modify your code so it can be compiled?
1. `getResult` throws `ErreurCalcul` but you expecting `CalcError`
2. `testDivision` does not have `throws` clause in its signature but you are expecting to catch `CalcError` that is checked exception

Comment: @mijer ErreurCalcul is the french for CalcError, I think that Jerôme was translating on the fly...

Comment: @mijer : fixed the error. Matthew was right, I translated on the fly and missed this one !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CalcError is an inner class, so you need to use

```
@Test(expected=Calculator.CalcError.class)
```

See [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

EDIT: You will need to declare the test method as throwing Calculator.CalcError as well:

```
@Test(expected=Calculator.CalcError.class)
public void testDivision() throws Calculator.CalcError {
    Calculator myCalc = new Calculator(10, 0);
    myCalc.setOperation(Calculator.Operation_e.DIVIDE);
    myCalc.getResult();
}
```

This is to please the compiler, because Calculator.CalcError is an checked Exception.

Comment: I thought about that and tried it, but then, I still get an error in the test for the line `myCalc.getResult();` : `Unhandled exception type Calculator.CalcError`

Comment: Added throws Calculator.CalcError on the test method

Answer (score 2):

`CalcError` is an inner class of `Calculator`. It is not imported by `import calculator.*;` You'd have to add `import calculator.Calculator.CalcError` or qualify `CalcError` (`expected=Calculator.CalcError.class`).

Answer (score 1):

Having public classes as inner classes is not a good idea. You should move that to its own file. Only private classes should be nested.
You could probably access the Error class by using `Calculator.CalcError.class` but I'd strong advise against it.

Apart from that I think JUnit lacks a bit of exception detection capabilities as you cannot set a message. I unit test for exceptions by catching them and then calling 
`Assert.fail` after the method call that should throw an exception:

```
try {
    someMethod();
    Assert.fail("SomeException should have been thrown");
catch(SomeException se) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since CalcError is an inner class to Calculator you need to reference it like this

```
@Test(expected=Calculator.CalcError.class)
public void testDivision() {
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is a checked exception, you need to add `throws Exception` to the method signature, otherwise the compiler will complain about the exception.