# How to unit test a kotlin coroutine that throws?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

(*Kotlin 1.5.21, kotlinx-coroutines-test 1.5.0*)

Please consider the following code inside a `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel`:

```
fun mayThrow(){
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, t -> throw t }
    vmScope.launch(dispatchers.IO + handler) {
        val foo = bar() ?: throw IllegalStateException("oops")
        withContext(dispatchers.Main) {
            _someLiveData.value = foo
        }
    }
}
```

`vmScope` corresponds to `viewModelScope`, in tests it is replaced by a `TestCoroutineScope`. The `dispatchers.IO` is a proxy to `Dispatchers.IO`, in tests it is a `TestCoroutineDispatcher`. In this case, the app's behavior is undefined if `bar()` returns null, so I want it to crash if that's the case. Now I'm trying to (JUnit4) test this code:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalStateException::class)
fun `should crash if something goes wrong with bar`()  {
    tested.mayThrow()
}
```

The test fails because of the very same exception it is supposed to test for:

```
Exception in thread "Test worker @coroutine#1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: oops
// stack trace

Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
// stack trace
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something quite obvious here... Question: is the code in my ViewModel the right way to throw an exception from a coroutine and if yes, how can I unit test it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912240/android-junit-testing-how-to-expect-an-exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit4 : testing for expected exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353173/junit4-testing-for-expected-exception)

Comment: both of the linked questions have very little in common with the one I'm asking. I know how to use JUnit4 and I also have a couple hundred of tests checking for expected exceptions. My problem is that the code under test is launching a **coroutine** and **something under the hood** seems to fail the test before it has a chance to complete. The question is how to figure out this "something". This question is not tagged "Java" for a good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why the test is green:

> code in `launch{ ... }` is beeing executed asynchronously with the
> test method. To recognize it try to modify `mayThrow` method (see code
> snippet below), so it returns a result disregarding of what is going
> on inside `launch {...}` To make the test red replace `launch` with
> `runBlocking` (more details in [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html), just read the first chapter
> and run the examples)

---

```
@Test
fun test() {
    assertEquals(1, mayThrow()) // GREEN
}

fun mayThrow(): Int {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, t -> throw t }

    vmScope.launch(dispatchers.IO + handler) {
        val foo = bar() ?: throw IllegalStateException("oops")
        withContext(dispatchers.Main) {
            _someLiveData.value = foo
        }
    }

    return 1 // this line succesfully reached
}
```

2. Why it looks like "test fails because of the very same exception ..."

> the test does not fail, but we see the exception stacktrace in console, because
> the default exception handler works so and it is applied, because in this case the custom exception handler `CoroutineExceptionHandler` throws ([detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834702))

3. How to test

Function `mayThrow` has too many responsibilities, that is why it is hard to test. It is a standard problem and there are standard treatments ([first](https://jonhilton.net/2016/03/29/coupling-tests-production/), [second](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222386)): long story short is apply Single responsibility principle.
For instance, pass exception handler to the function

```
fun mayThrow(xHandler: CoroutineExceptionHandler){
    vmScope.launch(dispatchers.IO + xHandler) {
        val foo = bar() ?: throw IllegalStateException("oops")
        withContext(dispatchers.Main) {
            _someLiveData.value = foo
        }
    }
}

@Test(expected = IllegalStateException::class)
fun test() {
    val xRef = AtomicReference<Throwable>()
    mayThrow(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, t -> xRef.set(t) })

    val expectedTimeOfAsyncLaunchMillis = 1234L
    Thread.sleep(expectedTimeOfAsyncLaunchMillis)

    throw xRef.get() // or assert it any other way
}
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks... though I don't like the idea of giving a custom exception handler as an argument (the function is actually private and called inside the init{} block), since I would have to inject it, adding yet another constructor argument (in addition to the Scope, because there is no lifycycleScope in test env). Wouldn't that be a use case for the `TestCoroutineExceptionHandler`?  Tried that, but it didn't work: `private val vmScope: CoroutineScope = TestCoroutineScope(coroutinesExceptionHandler)`

Comment: I don't see in the question what are you trying to test, so I can't give an exact answer. Anyway, if we follow the general idea "divide and conquer": attempt to isolate the piece that is subject for testing, add possibility to inject it (ctor or private-package field available from test), mock that piece in test and assert the state of the mock.

Comment: `mayThrow` is called in the init{ block} of the ViewModel, so the test setup prepares mocked dependencies for the following test: GIVEN `mocked.bar()` returns null WHEN creating a new instance of `MyViewModel ` THEN an IllegalStateException is thrown. Basically I need to make sure that the app crashes with the specified Exception because the real code uses a `CoroutineExceptionHandler` that throws.

Comment: I ended up injecting the `CoroutineExceptionHandler ` and replacing it with a TestCoroutineExceptionHandler in unit tests: `val result = exceptionHandler.uncaughtExceptions[0]` and then `assertThat(result).isInstanceOf(IllegalStateException::class.java)`. Accepting since this answer made me realize that I won't be able to test what I wanted following the approach I had in mind initially. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else works I can suggest to move the code, which throws an exception, to another method and test this method:

```
// ViewModel

fun mayThrow(){
    vmScope.launch(dispatchers.IO) {
        val foo = doWorkThatThrows()
        withContext(dispatchers.Main) {
            _someLiveData.value = foo
        }
    }
}

fun doWorkThatThrows(): Foo {
    val foo = bar() ?: throw IllegalStateException("oops")
    return foo
}

// Test

@Test(expected = IllegalStateException::class)
fun `should crash if something goes wrong with bar`()  {
    tested.doWorkThatThrows()
}
```

Or using [`JUnit Jupiter`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) allows to test throwing Exceptions by using [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-) method. Example:

```
assertThrows<IllegalStateException> { tested.doWorkThatThrows() }
```